# Como substituir aspas simples por aspas duplas no python?

Tags: python, csv, replace

Utilizei a função `replace` para substituir aspas simples de um campo no csv por aspas duplas, mas na saída o valor sai com caractere de escape \, é esse caractere permanece ao carregar para o hdts.

Linha de codigo:

```
txt_situ_mens = linha_csv[11].replace("/'", "/'")
```

Arquivo na entrada:

```
{'delivered': '2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000', 'read': '2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000', 'received': '2018-09-15 00:33:43+0000'}
```

Arquivo na Saida:

```
{\"delivered\": \"2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000\", \"read\": \"2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000\", \"received\": \"2018-09-15 00:33:43+0000\"}
```

Como gostaria que o arquivo saísse:
    {"delivered": '2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000", "read": "2018-09-15 00:35:00+0000", "received": "2018-09-15 00:33:43+0000"}

Comment: Não entendi sua pergunta poderia elaborar melhor?

Comment: Sim, porque o que você está exibindo é uma *string* e se a aspa não fosse escapada quebraria a sintaxe da linguagem: `"{"delivered": "2018-12-11", ...}"`

Comment: O que seria "carregar para o hdts"?